# How can I make job scheduler run every 5 minute at android 8

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I need every 5 minute to check internet connection and send request to the server .If internet is not  connected, I will make alert and change image view at tool bar .I used job scheduler .It does not work with 5 minutes . It works with minimum 15 minutes .

```
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(123,componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(15*60*1000)
            .build();
```

Comment: I believe 15 minutes is hardcoded in, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169179/295004 Check: [Guide to Background Processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background?hl=en)

Comment: I tried the first solution .It does not work with time less than 15 minutes .@MorrisonChang

Comment: Your requirement of <15 minutes means that you need to use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: They said alarm manager do not use at android 8 "oreo"

Comment: Don't know who "they" are. Also I just realized that your use case of notification when not on internet at such a high frequency doesn't make much sense, apps should handle the disconnected state.