# How to compare date with jobscheduler (< Android N)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I have a app where a user can set his own notification date. Since I'm using JobScheduler to check if the notification date matches the current date, I stumble upon a hurdle that is: The frequency/timeline of the JobScheduler has been set to 15 minutes, meaning that I can't compare the dates.

Example:

Let's say I add a notification date at 10:45 AM to notify me at 10:50 AM. Then the next check of the JobScheduler would be 11:00 AM (10:45 + 15 = 11:00). That would cause that my check (notification_date == current_date) would never match in this case.

How can I solve this problem? Are there any other ways of comparing this?

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: @Roger do you have any suggestion

Comment: Could you please post your code

Comment: The focus of this question is not in the code, but in the the comparison.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492022/job-scheduler-not-running-within-set-interval

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641278/job-scheduler-in-android-n-with-less-then-15-minutes-interval

Comment: Since this post has been marked as duplicate, I have to write my own awnser in my comments. I have solved this problem by using AlarmManager. I wasn't aware of that method by the time this question was asked.

Comment: ok...hope it solves